# Authorization backends in Django

Tags: django, authentication, authorization

Does Django have "Authorization backends"?

According to this page, it has them:

https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/authorization/

Up to now I only know "Authentication Backend"?

Answer (score 1):

Django has `permissions` system for Authorization.
ref https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: I read between your lines that there are no Authorization backends in Django. Is this correct?